# Qt Относительный путь к БД. QSqlQuery error "no such table. unable to execute statement"

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qtcreator

У меня есть проект, который я переношу из Visual Studio в QtCreator. Соответственно меняется и компилятор. И вот теперь проблема с работой с БД. В студии все это работало, а вот что не нравится QtCreator и MinGW не могу понять.
Конкретно проблема сводится к тому, что при обработке SQL-запроса он не видит таблицу. Если смотреть через SQLiteManager, то все таблицы на месте и запрос выполняется и дает нужный вывод.

Проблема тут:

```
QVector<QStringList> DbManager::showNotes()
{
    if (MattyNotesDb.isOpen())
    {
        QVector<QStringList> VectorOfNotes;

        QueryConstructor SelectAll;
        SelectAll.setTableName(QStringLiteral("Notes"));
        SelectAll.setOrderByClause("NoteId", Descending);

        QSqlQuery getNotesQuery;

        if( getNotesQuery.exec(SelectAll.constructSelectQuery())) // exec возвращает false
        {
            while (getNotesQuery.next()) // соответственно тоже возвращает false
            {
                QStringList Fields;
                for (int i = 0;i < 9;i++)
                {
                    Fields.push_back(getNotesQuery.value(i).toString());
                }
                VectorOfNotes.push_back(Fields);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            QMessageBox::critical(NULL, QObject::tr("Error"), getNotesQuery.lastError().text()); // no such table. Unable to execute statement
        }

        return VectorOfNotes;
    }
    else
    {
        showIsNotOpenError();
        return QVector<QStringList>();
    }
}
```

Подключение к БД:

```
bool DbManager::connect(const QString & path)
{
    MattyNotesDb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    MattyNotesDb.setDatabaseName(path); // path="MattyNotes.sqlite"

    if(QFile::exists(path)) // true
    {
        if (!MattyNotesDb.open()) // open=true, то есть if(false)
        {
            QMessageBox::critical(NULL, QObject::tr("Error"), MattyNotesDb.lastError().text());
            MattyNotesDb.close();

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Составление запроса:

```
QString QueryConstructor::constructSelectQuery()
{
    QString ResultQuery = "";

    if (TableName != "")
    {
        ResultQuery.append("SELECT ");

        if (WhatToSelectFieldNames.isEmpty())
        {
            ResultQuery.append("*");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0;i < WhatToSelectFieldNames.length()-1;i++)
            {
                ResultQuery.append(" " + WhatToSelectFieldNames[i] + ",");
            }
            ResultQuery.append(WhatToSelectFieldNames.last());
        }
        ResultQuery.append(" FROM " + TableName + constructWhereEqualsClause() + " " + OrderByClause);
    }
    return ResultQuery; // "SELECT * FROM Notes  ORDER BY NoteId DESC; " 
}
```

**UPD:**
Проблема в пути к файлу. Если вручную прописать полный путь, то все работает.

1.

```
 QString PathToDb = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/MattyNotes.sqlite";
```

Этот вариант в итоге присваивает переменной PathToDb значение "C:/Users/Matty/Documents/QtCreator/build-MattyNotes-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug/debug/MattyNo" Папка-то верная, но по какому поводу он обрезан?

2.

```
QString PathToDb = QDir::currentPath() + "/MattyNotes.sqlite";
```

Этот вариант присваивает значение "C:/Users/Matty/MattyNotes.sqlite" Вообще интересно, куда делись промежуточные папки.

3.

```
QString PathToDb = QFileInfo(".").absolutePath() + "/MattyNotes.sqlite";
```

Этот вариант выдает "C:/Users/MattyNotes.sqlite"

Что происходит? Как просто указать относительный путь, чтобы все в итоге работало на разных машинах?

И еще вопрос: почему

```
if(QFile::exists(path)) // true
if (!MattyNotesDb.open()) // open=true, то есть if(false)
```

эти строчки выдавали true, если на деле открытия БД не происходило?

Comment: Убедитесь что действительно подключаетесь к нужной базе. Правильно ли к базе путь указан, есть ли в пути русские символы, читаются ли другие таблицы?

Comment: Путь относительный, состоит только из названия файла: `  MattyNotesDb.setDatabaseName(path); // path="MattyNotes.sqlite"` Разве что он где-нибудь неявно подменяется на полный (может такое вообще быть?), так-то пробелы есть, но я в коде полный путь не использую. Сейчас пойду попробую другие таблицы.

Comment: Неа, на другие таблицы та же реакция.

Comment: Так, ок, перенос в другое место с путем без пробелов и русских символов + указание полного пути сработал. Тогда вопрос: почему относительный путь не работает? И почему при этом проходят проверки на наличие файла и открытие бд?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону кодировок исходников, насколько я помню gcc по-умолчанию ожидает utf8, а в студии win1251. Еще посмотрите в какой путь разворачивается относительный с помощью `QFileInfo(path).absoluteFilePath()`.

Comment: Да, на счет кодировок я знаю. А вот с путями какой-то хаос происходит. Сейчас добавлю это в вопрос

Comment: В посте обновленный вопрос. Посмотрите, если не сложно

Comment: @Matty, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запросу не назначена база данных. Попробуйте так:

```
QSqlQuery getNotesQuery(MattyNotesDb);
```

[QSqlQuery::QSqlQuery(QSqlDatabase db)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#QSqlQuery-3)

UPD. При запуске приложения из-под Qt Creator к программе применяется изменённое окружение. Текущим каталогом считается не тот, в котором находится исполняемый файл, а на один уровень выше. Чтобы узнать его точно, напишите в .pro-файле:

```
message($$OUT_PWD)
```

Программа выведет полный путь. Туда и положите ваш файл базы данных. А вообще драйвер sqlite создаёт новый файл базы данных, если указанный не существует. Поэтому вполне может быть, что база данных открылась, а указанной таблицы в ней нет. При обычном запуске приложения через двойной щелчок по файлу применяется обычное окружение. В этом случае файл базы данных должен лежать в той же папке, там же должны лежать необходимые DLL-файлы (Qt5Core.dll, Qt5Sql.dll, Qt5Widgets.dll и т.д.), а в папке sqldrivers должен лежать файл драйвера базы данных (qsqlite.dll, кажется. Находится в каталоге `$$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/sqldrivers)`

Если вы не хотите, чтобы Qt Creator применял изменённое окружение к программе, нажмите слева кнопку "Проекты", и далее внизу, где "Среда исполнения", выберите "Системная среда".

Comment: Нет, не помогло. Ничего не изменилось

Comment: Спасибо, разобралась. Еще есть вопрос, но уже не критичный. Можно как-нибудь попросить sqlite не создавать базу, если ее нет? Просто выводить ошибку типа "не найдено" или вообще ничего не делать.

Comment: @Matty, средствами драйвера - не знаю. Но у вас же есть проверка на существование файла `if(QFile::exists(path))`.

Comment: Так она и проходила... Хотя наверно эта строчка была добавлена чуть позже, когда драйвер уже успел создать пустую базу. Ок, всё, вопросов нет